# MVC model with multiple forms

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am passing a list to a view to display in a grid. Underneath the grid I have a form to allow the user to submit new values into the grid. When the controller is called the model always seems to be empty, I am not sure what I am doing wrong or if I should be doing this in a different way entirely.

The relavent parts of the view are as follows

```
@model IList<PSIApp.Models.PSM_StationTimetableView>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                <div class="panel-group">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse3">Hourly Update &#x25BC</a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse in" style="width:100%; margin-left:0%; margin-right:50px;">
                            <div class="mainformCollapse" style="width:100%; margin-left:0%; margin-right:50px;">
                                <p class="group-header">Hourly Update</p>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="example-text-input" class="col-xs-3 col-form-label" id="formLabelId">BP Issued</label>
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        @Html.MyTextBoxFor(p => p[0].PSM_StationBPData.BPIssued, new { @class = "generalformbox" }, false)
                                    </div>
                                    <label for="example-text-input" class="col-xs-3 col-form-label " id="formLabelId">BP Cancelled/Spoilt</label>
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p[0].PSM_StationBPData.BPSpoilt, new { @class = "generalformbox" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="example-text-input" class="col-xs-3 col-form-label" id="formLabelId">AV Issued</label>
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p[0].PSM_StationBPData.PostalReceived, new { @class = "generalformbox" })
                                    </div>
                                    <label for="example-text-input" class="col-xs-3 col-form-label" id="formLabelId">Tendered Issued</label>
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p[0].PSM_StationBPData.BPTendered, new { @class = "generalformbox" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input type="submit" value="Submit Hourly Update" class="standardsubmitbt" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult POControl(Models.PSM_StationBPData model)
{
return RedirectToAction("POControl");
}
```

Comment: Try checking what values you are posting from your browser or some tool like fiddler

Comment: Your generating form controls with indexers which means your controller method needs to be `public ActionResult POControl(List<Models.PSM_StationBPData> model)`. but the code makes no sense. You should have a view model containing properties for each property of `PSM_StationTimetableView` that you want to edit, plus a `IEnumerable<PSM_StationTimetableView> StationTimetableList` property for the collection to be displayed in the grid

Answer (score 0):

You are sending an IList of PSM_StationTimetableView, but you are expecting a PSM_StationBPData on the controller.